# SQL Select all rows on all columns on all tables that contain a string

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I dont really know SQL but have been tasked with importing content to a new WordPress site from an old one. All went well bar the internal links have kept the old site url. e.g post image url is:

```
www.oldsite.com/content/uploads/01/foo.jpg
```

instead of

```
www.newsiteurl.com/content/uploads/01/foo.jpg
```

I took a look through the DB via phpMyAdmin but could find no direct reference to the old site url - not even in the post's content.
New links in work fine but Im not about to trudge through 3 years worth of posts replacing urls.

Anyone know where this url is set? If not how can I search the WP SQL DB for all items of all tables for any cell that contains "oldurl.com"?

I already tried

```
SELECT * FROM * WHERE * LIKE '%oldurl%'
```

But phpMyAdmin told me SQL thought I was having it on; it said `#1064 you have an error in your syntax`

Comment: Are you selecting everything from everything where at least something?It is cool, but not valid – specify table name and search field in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Have you tried to use the WordPress export and import features, and failed? The WordPress team has worked all this stuff out. And, if that won't work for you, there are several site-migration plugins available.

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Also open up wp-config.php and check the old URL isn't being set as a constant

Comment: @notulysses Darn, so I have to run this for every field in every table? Gr

Comment: @OllieJones Used the import and it seemed to work fine apart from this  :\

Comment: @NathanDawson That worked for most of them! Turns out it *was* in the post_content in the posts table, despite my having looked there. Seems some still aren't behaving though and these were the ones I was checking when making changes to debug so there must be something else there. If you want to make that comment an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the tool at https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ As suggested by @NathanDawson. It's a really neat little plugin that found some entries I'd missed in the post_content table.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `WHERE * LIKE something` in a SQL statement. You Can't Do That™. You have to mention the specific column name.

The fields you're looking for are in the `wp_options` table. They have the `option_name`s of `siteurl` and `home`.

You really should use the built-in import and export features; this business of cloning a site by copying the data tables is somewhat tricky.

If you're spelunking and trying to figure out what's where, dump the database to an SQL file, then open that file up in a text editor, then search for things.

Comment: No, I used the import function. Apparently these links didnt get updated though for some reason. The items you mention were set to the new site url when I set the new site up initially and are still correct, so I really dont know where the old site url is coming from. It's like they were put in as absolute URLS rather than relative, but I cant find out where they would be stored in that case :\